# How to use awk {print} inside an inline ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, awk, terminal

I am trying to run an inline ssh command which looks like this:

`ssh user@127.0.0.1 "df / -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}'"`

I would expect the output to be `3.8G` (as this is the second line, third column) but instead, I am getting `/dev/sda1       6.9G  3.8G  2.8G  58% /`(the entire second line).

This means that the `FNR == 2` is working but the `{print $3}` is not.

If I run that command directly on the machine that I am ssh'ing into then I get the expected result, just not when calling it through an inline ssh command as above.

This code will eventually ran within a bash script. Is it not possible to use print in this way? If not, is there another method that you can suggest? I am relatively new to terminal life so please bear with me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Yes, it does indirectly answer my question and it is also very useful to know. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem resides in the way you pass you `ssh` arguments.

By calling:

```sh
ssh user@127.0.0.1 "df / -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}'"
```

You are passing two arguments:

- `user@127.0.0.1`
- `"df / -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}'"`

Since your second argument is given inside double quotes, the `$3` variable will be expanded. You can prevent this variable expansion by escaping the dollar sign:

```sh
ssh user@127.0.0.1 "df / -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print \$3}'"
```

Comment: nit: (a point which seems to cause a lot of confusion)  The 2nd argument passed to `ssh` does *not* contain double quotes.  `ssh` never sees them.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yup, you’re right, that’s why I said that the argument is given *inside* double quotes. But I cannot remove them when listing arguments, otherwise it would mean that I am evaluating the arguments before passing them (à la `set -x`) and we would not even see the `$3` which would be awkward at this point of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The joys of shell quoting. The line:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 "df / -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}'"
```

Is parsed by the shell, which invokes `ssh` with two arguments:

`user@127.0.01` and `df / -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print }'`  The `$3` was interpolated, and (I'm assuming) was empty.  To prevent that, you have many options.  One of which is:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 << \EOF
df / -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}'
EOF
```

another is:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 sh -c '"df / -h | awk '"'"'FNR == 2 {print $3}'"'"'"'
```